# Split String with delimiter "1.","2."and so on

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

i have a string as

"1.This should be a cause.2.this is a solution.Want to look for more?3.code is 234123.4.end of solution."

and i want to split it in a n array with "1.This should be a cause" then "2.this is a solution.Want to look for more?" then "3.code is 234123." and so on,

the code i tried is as follows:

```
Dim myString As String
myString = "1.This should be a cause.2.this is a solution.Want to look for more?    3.code is 234123.4.end of solution."

Dim solArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim solText As String

solArr = Split(myString, ".")
For i = 2 To UBound(solArr)
    solText = Mid(myString, InStr(1, myString, i - 1 & "."), InStr(1, myString, i & ".") - 1)

Next
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to split myString so that i could use it as 1.This should be a cause. , 2.this is a solution.Want to look for more? and so on...

Comment: how to know that `234123.` is not counted as `3.`?

Comment: actually i am looking for a better code to what i have so far....Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

while you would get in trouble having multiple times the same number + dot (and one is a delimiter) for all solutions I am able to think of, you still could use something like that:

```
Sub test()

  Dim myString As String
  myString = "1.This should be a cause.2.this is a solution.Want to look for more?    3.code is 234123.4.end of solution."

  Dim i As Long
  i = 2

  myString = Mid(Trim(myString), 3)

  While InStr(myString, i & ".")
    myString = Replace(myString, i & ".", "///", 1, 1)
    i = i + 1
  Wend

  Dim solArr As Variant

  solArr = Split(myString, "///")

  For i = 0 To UBound(solArr)
    solArr(i) = i + 1 & ". " & Trim(solArr(i))
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @jitendradeshmukh but it will fail for something like `1.This does not work.2. As you might think at point 4. 3. If you get what I mean. 4. Also for other cases.`

Comment: @DirkReichel how about splitting using every second `.` as a delimiter. I know this will fail if a note  has `.` in the text.

Comment: @Santosh as a bad example `1. Text 2. Some other text about the 3. which causes errors at the 3. part of the code. 3. is the problem for this extreme example. 3. 3. also could contain 3. to cause other errors. 3. is just messing everything up. 4. So in this example even I would not know for sure where to split.` at least not if I am a dumb machine :P

Comment: You could reduce the chance of a mismatch by ignoring `number.` where `number` is not `lastNumber + 1`

Comment: @alexk. What about my example? (comment) Where to cut for the 3rd part? A computer can't do it by logic (in terms of common sense). You need to apply a "rule" for the code so it knows what to do. But even if you check the char in front of `i` to be not numeric, it will fail at my example... the code I provided just goes for the first time it finds it (even if in front of an earlier `i`)... Just as an example to start with, but have a "not failable" code is impossible to my eye... also my code is bad in terms of that the string could contain my placeholder from the beginning. :/